# Android Downloadable Fonts for external source

Tags: android, google-fonts

Does it work with external font-source?
I have to use external source because some of the fonts styles I want to use is not in Google Fonts([link to google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)).

Comment: It does. You need to detail your question.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that if you use Google's downloadable fonts, Huawei phones without Google services, won't be able to download them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you surely can! But the best way would be to download the font on your desktop and copy them and paste them in this folder of the android studio.

> create a new `Asset` with directory name `font` by right clicking over the **app** then,
> add your downloaded fonts in the `font` directory